# MS Access AcDialog hiding the form

Tags: ms-access

I had a button click event in my access form which has

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmStudentsAll", acNormal, , , , acDialog
```

Clicking this button opened the frmStudentAll in dialog view but all of a sudden today clicking this button did not open the form. I thought Access was crashing everytime I clicked this button but I can still edit the VBA but I cannot press any of the buttons in GUI. My thought is that the acDialog is opening a really small form somewhere that I cannot see and I cannot press anything without closing it. I am having to close Access using task manager.

```
 DoCmd.OpenForm "frmStudentsAll", acNormal
```

Opening the form in just normal view works fine but this is not really what I want. I did not do any new Access updates recently. Not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the form does open, but is positioned off-screen.

This is a common issue when you have a multi-monitor setup or have different users with different resolutions using the database.

By default, Access stores the location of the form relative to the database window. If a specific user has two screens, or a very large screen, he can easily position it where others can't reach it. And even a single user can position it where he himself can't see it, by first positioning it on the first screen while Access is open on the second screen, and then opening Access on the first screen.

To avoid it, set *Auto Center* to *Yes* in the property pane for the form. That makes sure the form is always centered with respect to the Access application window, so always is on-screen as long as Access is on-screen.

Alternatively, when you're locked out of the database because of this issue so can't adjust the form, you can use `Forms!frmStudentsAll.Move 0,0` in the VBA Immediate window to reposition it. That way, you don't have to close the database when this occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help or not but, I'll throw it out there anyways. I had a similar problem when I had two monitors set up. Then lost one. There was one program that I would use all the time but, all of the sudden it wouldn't work. Took a while for it to kick in. That program was opening on the second screen that was no longer there. Just a shot in the dark... Good luck!